# How to position a movieclip with respect to the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Let's say I have a classA that is linked to movieClip in the library:

```
package {

    public class ClassA extends MovieClip {



      public function constructor() {

      }
    }
}
```

There is another movieClip linked to another class that I want to add  inside ClassA

package {

```
    public class ClassA extends MovieClip {

     private var obj:MovieClipFromLibrary();

      public function constructor() {

       obj = new MovieClipFromLibrary();
       obj.x = obj.y = 0;
       addChild(obj);

      }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is the movieclip that is linked to ClassA is small in size and placed at the center of the stage (like a dialog box on Android). But the "obj" movieClip is a rectangle and covers the entire stage. When I place it at (0,0), it gets positioned at the (0,0) of the "ClassA" MovieClip. What I want to do is the position it at (0,0) of the "Stage". How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`globalToLocal()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal()) to convert stage (global) coordinates to local coordinates:

```
var stageTopLeft:Point = this.globalToLocal(new Point(0, 0));
object.x = stageTopLeft.x;
object.y = stageTopLeft.y;
```

Comment: it didn't solve any problem.. I am still getting the same results as before.